# Should I migrate from OAuth1 to OAuth2?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have read about new Google Apps Marketplace and have seen the overview video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxX4oNi_Uyc).

I'm worried about migration from OAuth1 to OAuth2 and having impact to some developed applications with APIs in my domaine

in the video exactely in 24', comparaison of what libraries/APIs are used in the OAuth1 vs OAuth2, and in 27' talking about turning off the OAuth1.

these Libraries/API will be deprecated ?
Any idea about turning off the OAuth1 and when ?

Answer (score 0):

You need not worry about the impact of OAuth1 to OAuth2. This transition can be completed in a max of 15 days if you have done many integrations with Google. If you are worried just about the SSO with OAuth2 this can be completed in a day as Google has already provided proper documentation regarding the work flow.

Google has even provided migration APIs to upgrade your customers domains from v1 to v2 of Google Apps Marketplace(GAM). If you have a huge user base to be migrated then you need to plan accordingly such that migrated and non-migrated users would be able to use your app for some days till the migration is completed successfully.

```
Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those Google Documents List API versions and features identified at http://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/documents-list-api-list without these changes until April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable good faith judgment):
```

So on a safe side it is better to migrate all of your APIs to the latest libraries to avoid any failures at a later point of time. Anyway the older versions are not supported for any issue fixes/ support from Google side. So it is always better to migrate your APIs

Older version of GAM(v1) will also be deprecated at some time but Google hasn't provided any timeline for this. Probably it may take a year(not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Google strongly encourages you to migrate your marketplace application to OAuth2 as soon as possible. Google has already announced deprecation of OAuth1. All top apps on marketplace have migrated their customers to OAuth2 with no issues. We plan to stop allowing installs of OAuth1 applications in near future from the marketplace (specific timelines to be communicated separately).

Comment: Yes but my own applications work just for my domain and not listed in the Marketplace and i'm used to work with old apis ans scopes (docs api and scopes instead of drive ones for example...) is there any future impact ?

Comment: @user3259378 we're in the process of migration, and suddenly we have started receiving `Token invalid - Target is disabled` error on our old listing, problem outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350517/token-error-in-google-apps-marketplace-application Does it have anything to do with the OAuth migration, so that we know how to fix it?